# pdfbox 3.0 - getting invalid pdf after ExternalSigningSupport.sign

Tags: validation, pdfbox, signature

My problem is getting invalid pdf(modified after signing) after call `ExternalSigningSupport.sign`.

I have pre-made p#7 as a hex string.

What I implemented till now looks like below

Test Runner

```java
public class TestPdf {

    private static final String TEST_P7_HEX = "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";

    @Test
    public void test() {
        PdfService<PDSignature, PDDocument> sut = new PdfBoxService();

        PDSignature signature = new PDSignature();
        // Add Sign
        signature.setFilter(PDSignature.FILTER_ADOBE_PPKLITE);
        signature.setSubFilter(PDSignature.SUBFILTER_ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);
        signature.setName("MyName");
        signature.setContactInfo("myEmail@email.com");
        signature.setLocation("Seoul, South Korea");
        signature.setReason("Sign a pdf document");
        signature.setSignDate(Calendar.getInstance());

        // Generate SignatureInterface with ready-made hex string
        Pkcs7TestSignature pkcs7TestSignature = new Pkcs7TestSignature(TEST_P7_HEX);

        File inFile = new File(UNSIGNED_PDF_FILE);
        PDDocument document = Loader.loadPDF(inFile);
        File outFile = new File(SIGNED_EXTERNAL_PDF_FILE);
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
        sut.signExternalAndSave(document, signature, pkcs7TestSignature, outputStream);
    }
}
```

Signature interface for pre-made p#7.

```java
public class Pkcs7TestSignature implements SignatureInterface {

    private final String hexEncoded;

    public Pkcs7TestSignature(String hexEncoded){
        this.hexEncoded = hexEncoded;
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] sign(InputStream inputStream) {
        return HexUtils.convertToBytes(hexEncoded);
    }
}
```

Service Under Test like..

```java
public class PdfBoxService implements PdfService<PDSignature, PDDocument> {

    private static final SignatureOptions signatureOptions;
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PdfBoxService.class);

    static {
        signatureOptions = new SignatureOptions();
    }

    @Override
    public void signExternalAndSave(PDDocument originalDocument, PDSignature signature, SignatureInterface signatureInterface, OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {
        originalDocument.addSignature(signature, signatureInterface, signatureOptions);
        ExternalSigningSupport externalSigningSupport = originalDocument.saveIncrementalForExternalSigning(outputStream);
        byte[] externalSignature = signatureInterface.sign(externalSigningSupport.getContent());

        // As far as I know, file will be created at this moment
        externalSigningSupport.setSignature(externalSignature);
        originalDocument.close();
    }
}
```

When I open the result pdf with Acrobat reader, I can see the signature and certificate details.
However, it says my signature is invalid since the document is modified or corrupted.

As far as I know, the `ExternalSigningSupport` was implemented to care this situation so I am pretty sure something is missing.

What am I missing?

Comment: `UNSIGNED_PDF_FILE ` and `SIGNED_PDF_FILE ` are just absolute pdf paths

Comment: *What exactly does your pre-generated signature sign*? The data it should sign does not exist before the `originalDocument.saveIncrementalForExternalSigning` call and can then be retrieved using `externalSigningSupport.getContent()` but you ignore that content and use a signature of something else.